# xrdp connection:- Displays only a part of remote machine before disconnecting itself

Tags: 22.04, display, xrdp

So basically I am using freerdp to remote into a machine but the issue is I can only see a part of what needs to be displayed. I have used xrandr to properly align both the VM to 1920x1080 but even then the display is only part of it and right after 20 sec or so it disconnects it self with following messages which don't seem odd to me.

[image: What is being displayed ?]
[image: Messages]

Note:- When I use windows remote desktop connection to connect to this VM is connects and works properly so it seems the problem lies in client. The client is ubuntu 22.04.3 server running  xfce4 for desktop.

The network disconnect is least of my worries ATM. I cannot figure out why the display is not working properly ? Is it the kernel drivers or something else?.